# Android Studio Beta Version (Preview) / Android Sludio

Tags: android-studio

Can we use Android Studio Beta version for development Process?

Comment: ""+new Date(number)

Comment: Is that milliseconds since Jan 1 1970?

Comment: Please [search](/help/searching) before posting. Every single possible question about how to create a date from a seconds value (that's not milliseconds, or it's not from The Epoch) and how to format a date in JavaScript has been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to get date from timestamp

```
 timestamp=1496915573   
    var todate=new Date(timestamp).getDate();
    var tomonth=new Date(timestamp).getMonth()+1;
    var toyear=new Date(timestamp).getFullYear();
    var original_date=tomonth+'/'+todate+'/'+toyear;
```